# Pip: Uses several environment markers for a single package

Tags: pip, markers

I want to use several environments markers for `pywin32`, and I cannot figure out a way to combine them. Individually it works, but not together:

```
pywin32==228;{python_version<'3', platform_system=='Windows'}
pywin32;{python_version>='3', platform_system=='Windows'}
```

So:

```
pywin32==228;python_version<'3'
pywin32;python_version>='3'
```

Works fine, and same for `platform_system` alone, but I cannot get to combine the two. I already tried several options and can't find someone who ran into the same issue.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0496/#examples :

> backports.ssl_match_hostname >= 3.4 ; python_version < '2.7.9' or (python_version >= '3.0' and python_version < '3.4')

It's just a Python expression. So in your case it's:

```
pywin32==228; python_version<'3' and platform_system=='Windows'
```